# Fetch Data from another Fragments to Fragment in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment

[image: 2 Fragments in Tab in Another Fragment]

I have that requirement, i have one Main Fragment in which there is a Tab having 2 Fragments, In that Screen "Save Button" is fixed which is in Main Fragment. 
What all i want to do is, when user click on Save Button i want to save data of Fragments of Tab1 & Tab2 by the service which run from Main Fragment. Means i want to fetch data of both Tab Fragments to Main Fragment.
Please help me, i search a lot but didn't found any solution on that, i tried that using methods but it gives me nullPointerException and fragment not attached errors.

> I do not use Activity as Main Screen cause my Main Fragment itself is a Tab Fragment Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to directly communicating between fragments as per the documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

> Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly

You have to use **interface** to achieve this

Comment: Yes, i saw that, but my Main Fragment itself is a Tab Fragment so there is no way to make it Activity

Answer (score 0):

there is not direct communication in android between 2 fragments but you can use subscribe and listen desgin pattern to solve this problem you can make it on your own interfaces and listener and you can use lib like

[Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/README.md)

**EventBus in 3 steps**

Define events:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Prepare subscribers: Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register and unregister your subscriber. For example on Android, activities and fragments should usually register according to their life cycle:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

Post events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication between `Fragment`s is done via parent `Activity`. `Fragment` should obtain `Activity` instance and pass data/events to it.

Activity should decide what to do with it - possibly pass it to some other fragment or multiple fragments.

Activity can obtain attached fragments via `FragmentManager` API.

In your `TabFragment` you sould call activity (pseudo-code):

```
void onClickedSave() {
    getActvity().onHandleClickedSave();
}
```

In activity:

```
void onHandleClickedSave() {
    tab1 = findTab1Fragment()
    tab1.handleSave()
    tab2 = findTab2Fragment()
    tab2.handleSave()
}
```

Of course you need to implement the plumbing yourself.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

BTW, your problem will be solved if you use MVVM design pattern. Android has support for it in support library.

Answer (score 0):

You can not communicate between fragments directly.
There are several ways to communicate between fragments

- Using Activity
- Using Handler
- Using Interface